# Avoiding The "No EGLConfig found!" Error

Tags: android, andengine

one of my users are reporting this error for my game.

i am using andengine as my engine. Here is the error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig found!
at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:183)
at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:157)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:916)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1246)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
```

My question is, is there anything i can do to avoid this error?

Comment: It may also be worth noting that OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supported in the emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception appears if you use custom rom on your device, like cyanogenmod. And there is no way to prevent it.

http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/no-eglconfig-found-t6129.html

Comment: Well, this is not true, at least not anymore. I have the latest cyanogenmod on my SGS and I'm running the andengine just fine.

Comment: Nice to hear it a year later. :)

Comment: @BoJIHanpocmombI This is SO, where questions/answers/comments are always relevant, regardless of the time span between them.

Comment: It also happened to me when using genymotion emulator

Answer (score 4):

You must enable the emulator GPU.

To do this in Eclipse go to Window > AVD Manager select your AVD and click "Edit...".

Check the "Use Host GPU" box, then save and restart your AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Create AVD with Target 4.0.3 -API Level 15 with GPU Emulation yes. My example stated running after this. IF you have further problem visit [AndEngine Forum and get detail about OpenGL drivers](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/no-eglconfig-found-t6129-40.html)