# Android AndEngine problems: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig Found

Tags: java, android, andengine

Good evening!

I have been tinkering around with the AndEngine for game development in Android. I tried to run a Tower of Hanoi game application that uses the AndEngine, but the aformentioned error keeps running when I run it in the emulator. Here is the LogCat:

```
09-05 21:34:00.948: D/dalvikvm(633): No JNI_OnLoad found in   /data/data/com.tutorial.towerofhanoi/lib/libandengine.so 0x4101f730, skipping init
09-05 21:34:01.017: D/AndEngine(633): TowerOfHanoiActivity.onResume @(Thread: 'main')
09-05 21:34:01.067: I/dalvikvm(633): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-05 21:34:01.137: I/dalvikvm(633): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 21:34:01.207: D/libEGL(633): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
09-05 21:34:01.207: D/libEGL(633): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
09-05 21:34:01.238: W/dalvikvm(633): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
09-05 21:34:01.297: E/AndroidRuntime(633): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 85
09-05 21:34:01.297: E/AndroidRuntime(633): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig found!
09-05 21:34:01.297: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:183)
09-05 21:34:01.297: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:157)
09-05 21:34:01.297: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1009)
09-05 21:34:01.297: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1362)
09-05 21:34:01.297: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
09-05 21:34:01.309: D/gralloc_goldfish(633): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-05 21:34:01.497: D/AndEngine(633): TowerOfHanoiActivity.onPause @(Thread: 'main')
09-05 21:34:03.867: I/Process(633): Sending signal. PID: 633 SIG: 9
```

The line of code affected by the error is at the AndEngine library itself, particularly this line:

```
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No " + EGLConfig.class.getSimpleName() + " found!");
```

The screenshot shows the target I am building. It's API15 Android 4.0.3

[image]

How do I remedy this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding The "No EGLConfig found!" Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069264/avoiding-the-no-eglconfig-found-error)

Comment: Rest assured I am using only the 4.0.3 emulator in the SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with this line

`09-05 21:34:01.207: D/libEGL(633): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.`

recreate or edit your emulator and be sure that under the hardware list you have

`GPU Emulation`  set to    `Yes`

Comment: This was the missing step in those other other questions similar to mine. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I had problem like this.
My solution (need editing AVD):

1. Enable "Use Host GPU"
2. I changed CPU/ABI to "Intel Atom (x86)"
3. I changed Target from API Level 17 to API Level 15 (Android 4.0.3)

And it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the emulator GPU.

To do this in Eclipse go to Window > AVD Manager select your AVD and click "Edit...", check the "Use Host GPU" box, then save and restart your AVD.