# android opengl error (Application unexpectedly stopped)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-emulator, andengine

I'm developing this game for android. I'm following a tutorial on how to make menus. And this is the code. There's no errors just warning in the code so I dont know what to do.

```
08-23 21:31:41.099: E/System(79): Failure starting core service
08-23 21:31:41.099: E/System(79): java.lang.SecurityException
08-23 21:31:41.099: E/System(79): at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-23 21:31:41.099: E/System(79): at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)

08-23 21:31:41.099: E/System(79): at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)

08-23 21:31:41.099: E/System(79): at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206)

08-23 21:31:41.139: E/EventHub(79): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
08-23 21:31:41.139: E/EventHub(79): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter

08-23 21:31:42.049: E/SoundPool(79): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg

08-23 21:31:42.049: E/SoundPool(79): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg

08-23 21:31:42.069: E/SoundPool(79): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg

08-23 21:31:42.069: E/SoundPool(79): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
08-23 21:31:42.079: E/SoundPool(79): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
08-23 21:31:42.159: E/UsbObserver(79): java.lang.NullPointerException

08-23 21:31:42.159: E/UsbObserver(79):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131)
08-23 21:31:42.159: E/UsbObserver(79):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.<init>(UsbObserver.java:65)

08-23 21:31:42.159: E/UsbObserver(79):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402)

08-23 21:31:47.820: E/ThrottleService(79): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf

08-23 21:31:47.880: E/ThrottleService(79): Error reading data file

08-23 21:31:49.250: E/logwrapper(194): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
08-23 21:31:49.320: E/logwrapper(195): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
08-23 21:31:49.370: E/logwrapper(196): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
08-23 21:31:57.759: E/logwrapper(225): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
08-23 21:31:57.889: E/logwrapper(226): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
08-23 21:31:58.000: E/logwrapper(227): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
08-23 21:32:41.593: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(34): failed to extract an album art
08-23 21:33:17.502: E/ThrottleService(79): Error reading data file
08-23 22:06:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(414): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 13
08-23 22:06:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(414): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig found!

08-23 22:06:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:183)

08-23 22:06:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:157)

08-23 22:06:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:919)

08-23 22:06:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1264)

08-23 22:06:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(414):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

Comment: You said 'this is the code' but I think you forgot to post it. What tutorial are you following? Finally, I suggest looking at the stack trace, and finding the line from your code that seems to be causing / starting the error, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying this in an emulator - it's probably not configured properly. See my answer to this question - [Android AndEngine problems: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282901/android-andengine-problems-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-eglconfig-fou)

Answer (score -2):

Changed already the target SDK, enable GPU Host, the processor to Intel. Still getting errors

08-25 01:41:48.889: ERROR/Zygote(793): setreuid() failed. errno: 30
08-25 01:42:01.820: ERROR/Zygote(793): setreuid() failed. errno: 30
08-25 01:42:04.430: ERROR/BatteryService(853): acOnlinePath not found
08-25 01:42:04.430: ERROR/BatteryService(853): usbOnlinePath not found
08-25 01:42:04.430: ERROR/BatteryService(853): batteryStatusPath not found
08-25 01:42:04.430: ERROR/BatteryService(853): batteryHealthPath not found
08-25 01:42:04.430: ERROR/BatteryService(853): batteryPresentPath not found
08-25 01:42:04.430: ERROR/BatteryService(853): batteryCapacityPath not found
08-25 01:42:04.430: ERROR/BatteryService(853): batteryVoltagePath not found
08-25 01:42:04.430: ERROR/BatteryService(853): batteryTemperaturePath not found
08-25 01:42:04.430: ERROR/BatteryService(853): batteryTechnologyPath not found
08-25 01:42:04.770: ERROR/EGL_emulation(853): rcMakeCurrent returned EGL_FALSE
08-25 01:42:04.770: ERROR/EGL_emulation(853): tid 874: eglMakeCurrent(984): error 0x3006 (EGL_BAD_CONTEXT)

08-25 01:42:04.770: ERROR/libEGL(853): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

08-25 01:42:04.770: ERROR/libEGL(853): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

08-25 01:42:04.770: ERROR/libEGL(853): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

08-25 01:42:04.770: ERROR/libEGL(853): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

08-25 01:43:01.773: ERROR/Zygote(889): setreuid() failed. errno: 30

Comment: Please remove this and edit your question with this information appended. The box in which you typed this in is for answers, not additional information.