# WorkLight - No suitable EGL configs found

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, egl

I have an application in worklight and am getting an error when running the application on android. As log below:

```
02-13 08:19:07.470: W/chromium(942): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
02-13 08:19:07.590: E/chromium(942): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
02-13 08:19:07.590: E/chromium(942): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-13 08:19:07.600: E/chromium(942): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
02-13 08:19:07.600: E/chromium(942): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-13 08:19:07.600: E/chromium(942): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
```

Comment: Attach code that generate the error

Comment: Is this executing on a device or an emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this related question is relevant to you: [Avoiding The "No EGLConfig found!" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069264/avoiding-the-no-eglconfig-found-error)

If you are using an unofficial ROM for your device, this message may appear and there is no way to prevent it.